# Unlocking Seagate Drive with forgotten ATA user password, "bad sense data" error?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, sata, ata

I'm trying to unlock a hard drive that was given to me with an unknown user password. My research seems to suggest that this is possible with `hdparm` if one knows the master password. Resources online claim that Seagate drives have a master password of `Seagate[25 spaces]` Attempting to issue the master password to unlock the drive gives the following error message:

```
sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-unlock 'Seagate                         ' /dev/sdb
security_password: "Seagate                         "

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="Seagate                         ", user=master
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Here is the `hdparm -I` output:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST4000VN000-1H4168                      
    Serial Number:      Z305NX6Z
    Firmware Revision:  SC46    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x001f) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  7814037168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     3815447 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     4000787 MBytes (4000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5900
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 254
    Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 128
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
       *    Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    Media Card Pass-Through
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    unknown 119[6]
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
            unknown 78[7]
            unknown 78[11]
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    478min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 478min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c50087bdc5c0
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 087bdc5c0
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: It is probably not as simple as you are thinking to break a HDD password. Else, what would be the point of a HDD password.

Comment: @John People have reported success using the method above, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/712849/how-to-unlock-an-ssd-disk-with-hdparm) for example.